# rss feeds are announced as new multiple times

Tags: youtube, rss

I'm using Claws Mail with RSSyl (on Debian) to subscribe to some rss feeds.
A few days ago i subscribed to an Youtube feed (Youtube offers rss feed at "http://youtube.com/rss/user/*username*/videos.rss".
Now i have the problem that some of the entries get announced again, even though I read them the last day (and marked them as read).
This problems appears also with rss feeds from Bitbucket. This also appeared with Akregator (The KDE RSS reader).

Please note that there are other feeds which work just like expected.

Does anyone know what I can do against this? Can I even do anything or is this something only the providers of these feeds can solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because these RSS feeds include informations like the view count (in the case of youtube). The behaviour of announcing feeds as new when the content has changed can be changed in claws mail by right-clicking on the feed directory and then going to feed-preferences.